# Gedit problem cpp file is not created

Tags: gedit

When i open terminal I type
`Mkdir name` of folder
`Cd name` of folder
When I write `gedit x.cpp` the cpp file is not created and the file doesn't open to write the code 
Any ideas why this happens? 
I even added quotations after gedit but still 
The cpp file was not created.

Comment: Why do you write `mkdir` and `cd` capitalized?

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure you have permissions to create files in this directory? Maybe Gedit is not working correctly, try reinstalling it using `sudo apt-get purge gedit` and `sudo apt-get install gedit`. I have no other ideas.

Comment: When i entered sudo a message appeared command couldnt be found